# What is the meaning of "get the object to do it for you"?

Tags: oop

I've read this piece of advice in "The Pragmatic Programmer" Book, but I didn't understand it.

> If you need to change an object’s state, get the object to do it for
> you.

What is the meaning of an object's state, and how to get the object to do it itself?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this `Person` class:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;
    
    public void Person(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.age = age;
    }
    
    public void changeName(String newName, String lastName) {
      this.firstName = newName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public void celebrateBirthday() {
      this.age += 1;
    }
}
```

> What is the meaning of an object's state

An objects state is the value of its fields.  In the `Person` class above, if you created an instance:

```
Person john = new Person("John", "Smith", 42);
```

Then the state of the `john` object is currently `firstName="John"`, `lastName="Smith"`, and `age=42`

> and how to get the object to do it itself?

This is a different wording of the popular OOP adage of "tell, don't ask" (You can Google that for lots of hits if you want).

One of the main goals of OOP is to try and *minimize* the scope of mutable data.  One of the ways you can to that is by hiding your data in a class, and only allowing it to be mutated by a select number of public methods on that class.  In our `Person` class above, the only way to mutate its state is through the public methods `changeName` and `celebrateBirthday`.  When you call a method on an object which results in that object's state being mutated, such as

```
john.celebrateBirthday();  // John is now one year older!
```

You are "getting the object to do it itself" by calling one of the object's methods.

This is in contrast to *not* asking the object to do it itself by directly mutating `john`'s state from somewhere else, for example:

```
public main() {
    Person john = new Person("John", "Smith", 42);
    
    // Celebrate birthday.  Just for demonstration.  Doesn't actually work.
    john.age += 1;
}
```

By reducing the scope of a mutable variable, and programming with "tell, don't ask" in mind, you are generally making your program easier to reason about, and potentially debug if need be.